# polynomial over $\mathbb{C}[X]$ that complex conjugates a finite set of normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I was wondering if there exists a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ for any finite set of normal matrices with the property $p(A)=A^*$. I think the choice of the coefficients of $p$ probably has something to do with all the eigenvalues of the normal matrices... but im not sure. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such a polynomial does exist.

Let $\{z_1,\ldots,z_n\}$ be the set of all eigenvalues of all matrices considered.

Take $p$ to be any polynomial such that $$p(z_i)=\bar z_i,$$
for every $i$.

Then this polynomial satisfies
$$p(A)=A^*,$$ for every $A$ in your finite set.  To prove this it is enough to do the computation in a basis that diagonilizes $A$.